# VMWare Error "Cannot change network to bridged" after update to 17.0.2

Tags: vmware-workstation

After updating VMWare from 17.0.1 to 17.0.2, I can no longer use a Bridged network. When I try to select it in the VMWare Virtual Network Editor, I get the error "Cannot change network to bridged: There are no un-bridged host network adapters." When I select "Restore Defaults", I just get VMnet1 and VMnet8 back as network adapters, no VMnet0 (Auto-bridged) adapter (as would be "normal"). I can add VMNet0 back in as Host-only, but can't change it to Bridged.
[image]

I've reinstalled network drivers; I've tried all network configurations I can think of, no luck. I even went back and re-installed 17.0.1, and it still fails. This leads me to believe the update screwed up something in my host computer, but at this point I don't know what.

[image: after "restore defaults"]

Answer (score 0):

As some have mentioned on other forums, the only answer that worked was:

1. Uninstall antivirus
2. Uninstall VMWare
3. Re-install VMWare
4. Re-install antivirus.

Some of those steps require I.T. at my company, so we tried to avoid this route because of how long that was going to take, but nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that was introduced in version 17.0.1: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Wireless-bridge-mode-not-working-on-Linux-VMs-when-running/td-p/2952353

The only workaround I found is to reinstall (and stay on) version 17.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This bug was introduced in version 17.X, but a workaround exists.

1- [ Windows Safe Mode ] Restart your computer and go to the safe mode

2- Open device manager

3- Expand "network adapters"

4- Uninstall all of the network adapters in the list ( Be careful and if you do not know what you are uninstalling and how to get it back, consult with a pro!!! )

5- Restart your system

6- Open the device manager

7- click on your system name at the top of the list

8- Right-click and click on "Scan for hardware changes"

9- Close the device manager and open the VMware workstation

10- Click on the Edit tab and open "Virtual network editor"

11- Click on Change settings at the bottom right

12- Click on "Restore default" and let it do the the job

***** THE PROBLEM SHOULD BE SOLVED AT THIS POINT *****

13- Reconfigure your Virtual network settings